# Php mysql WHERE clause error

Tags: php, mysql, where-clause

Can anyone see why this isn't working?

```
$category = 1;
$CategoryResult = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM Category WHERE Index = '$category'");
if (!$CategoryResult) 
    die("Could not retrieve results from category $category: " . mysql_error());
```

Mysql error as follows:

> Could not retrieve results from category 1: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'Index = '1'' at line 1

Index is an auto-increment primary key of the table Category.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should be your code

```
$category = 1;
$CategoryResult = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM Category WHERE `Index` = $category");
if (!$CategoryResult) 
    die("Could not retrieve results from category $category: " . mysql_error());
```

Normally I would preach about mysql_real_escape_string, but if $category is *under your control* (such as from another query) - and it is guaranteed to be an int, then this code is safe.

- `Index` is a reserved word - it must be backticked
- Do **not** quote numerics. MySQL does has rules to convert (string) literals being compared to numbers, but unless you are familiar with the rules, just use proper numbers.

Example

```
select * from
(
select 1 `index`
union all
select 2
union all
select 3
) X
where `index` = '1-2-3-4'
   or `index` = '3.0Y!'
```

Output

```
`index`
1
3
```

Comment: Your last statement is incorrect. MySql will convert it to a number.

Comment: @The Scrum Meister - You are right. I updated the answer to make it a warning/recommendation instead.

Answer (score 3):

maybe index is a reserved word . try this

```
$CategoryResult = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM Category c WHERE c.`Index` = '$category'");
```

and check if index is a string or an integer

Comment: This is probably it. `index` is a very bad column name, I would change it.

Answer (score 1):

Two problems I can see. If it is a primary key, you should be using WHERE Index = " . $category . ")

Secondly, Index is a reserved word in MySQL.

Answer (score 1):

You should quote `Index`, as it's a MySQL keyword; like:

```
SELECT * FROM Category WHERE `Index` = $category;
```

And the single quotes are unnecessary and incompatible to ANSI SQL, assuming `$category` is numeric.